# Changing background color of Frame

Tags: java, awt, frame

I just started Java AWT programming.I can't change background color of my frame.!Here is my code..and below that error..Plz tell me why I'm facing this error and how to get rid of that..
Thanks in advance!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class F1 extends Frame
{  

  public void paint(Graphics g)
 {
  g.drawString("Hi",200,300); 

 }


public static void main(String args[])
 {
  F1 f = new F1();
  f.setVisible(true);
  f.setSize(1500,1500);
  f.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
  f.setTitle("First fRAME");
  f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
  {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent x)
 {
  System.exit(0);

 }

  });

}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is Color class imported in your code ?

Comment: No..it was not . I had imported awt package..' import java.awt.* ' then it was giving error...now as you said I imported it in individual manner..like ' import java.awt.Color ' and it has gone..Why??

Comment: I am not quite sure.. but same thing happened with me before... I think it happen with some other package also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me. Are you sure to have imported all required packages?

- `import java.awt.Color;`

[image: Blue frame]

Try with this code, which is the simplest you can do to check if the problem is due to set background color or is due to something other:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;



public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Frame frame = new Frame("Title");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Importing Color class individually solved my problem..Thanks for that..But why to import class Color individually??I've imported the whole package awt it should anyway work...

Comment: Yes, even with your import system (all `awt` and `awt.event` packages) the code works. Perhaps the problem was something else, maybe in your `F1` class or somewhere else in your project.